# How to add a list of specific object in a configuration file for a WorkerService

Tags: c#, list, app-config, appsettings, worker-service

As far as what I understand:

- WorkerService is the new way to define a Windows Service (app that run as as service).
- By default, using the contextual menu on the project, the type of configuration file associated to a WorkerService is stil a xaml file: "App.config". See: [How to: Add an application configuration file to a C# project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2022)
- According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022), I understand that I should use the section `<appsettings>`.

appSettings is a dictionary of key value pair. But I can't find how to add a list of item as the value. Also, I would like to add my own object as the value if possible.

Is there a way to add a List of MyConfigObject (`List<MyConfigObject>`)into a config file? If yes, how? Should I use another section or should I use another type of config file (json, yaml) to have the simplest way to read/write settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, Like this:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyConfigObject": [
    {
      "Prop1": "1",
      "Prop2": "2"
    },
    {
      "Prop1": "1",
      "Prop2": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**MyConfigObject Class**

```
public class MyConfigObject
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

In Startup, register the Configuration with the type `MyConfigObject`. Like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<List<MyConfigObject>>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfigObject"));
    }
```

Now you can use it in any service or controller, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly List<MyConfigObject> myConfig;
        public HomeController(IOptions<List<MyConfigObject>> myConfig, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.myConfig = myConfig.Value;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your answer is just awesome. I'm currently developping a windows service and there is no "services" by default. I'm looking to see what's the best way to implement your suggestion with the fewer dependency on the "services". I would like to depends only the JSON reader and property matcher. But I will see if there is already a "services" OR if I should add one into a windows service OR if I can just read the config without going with IOC(services). I will get back to you when I will find some answers...

Answer (score 0):

For the those who wonder how to get a JSON config section into an object without injection into a services:

```
var appFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(appFolder, "appsettings.json"))
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    IConfigurationSection sectionMyConfigObject = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfigObject));
    var myConfigObject = sectionMyConfigObject.Get<List<MyConfigObject>>();
```

For file appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyConfigObject": [
    {
      "Prop1": "1",
      "Prop2": "2"
    },
    {
      "Prop1": "1",
      "Prop2": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```